# JSON.NET: Unknown members handling on deserialization

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm using JSON for data interchange. And I'm using JSON.NET framework.

I have the class:

```
public class CarEntity
{
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

And I have following code:

```
public void Test()
{
    var jsonString = 
    @"{
      ""Model"": ""Dodge Caliber"",
      ""Year"": 2011,
      ""Price"": 15000,
      ""Mileage"": 35000
    }";
    var parsed = (CarEntity)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString, typeof(CarEntity));
}
```

Since there are no "Mileage" field in CarEntity class I need log warning about it:

> Unknown field: Mileage=35000

Is there some way to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is little tricky but you can. Change your code to:

```
var parsed = (CarEntity)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString, typeof(CarEntity), new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error,
    Error = ErrorHandler
});
```

And add:

```
private static void ErrorHandler(object x, ErrorEventArgs error)
{
    Console.WriteLine(error.ErrorContext.Error);
    error.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
}
```

You should probably do more with the last line, because now every error will not throw an exception.

**UPDATE**

Decompiled code form invoking exception in Json.NET:

```
if (this.TraceWriter != null && this.TraceWriter.LevelFilter >= TraceLevel.Verbose)
    this.TraceWriter.Trace(TraceLevel.Verbose, JsonPosition.FormatMessage(reader as IJsonLineInfo, reader.Path, StringUtils.FormatWith("Could not find member '{0}' on {1}", (IFormatProvider) CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, (object) propertyName, (object) contract.UnderlyingType)), (Exception) null);
if (this.Serializer.MissingMemberHandling == MissingMemberHandling.Error)
    throw JsonSerializationException.Create(reader, StringUtils.FormatWith("Could not find member '{0}' on object of type '{1}'", (IFormatProvider) CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, (object) propertyName, (object) contract.UnderlyingType.Name));
reader.Skip();
```

Comment: Do not works. JsonSerializationException was thrown and ErrorHandler was ommitted.

Comment: Full code is here: http://pastebin.com/zjztsZDx. If you have problems show me your code

Comment: Ok, thank you. It was issue for JSON.NET version 4.0. When I've updated to version 5.0 ErrorHandler was called. But still no solution for my question. How can I know that unknown member is a reason of error? I have exception message: "Could not find member 'Mileage' on object of type 'CarEntity'..." But parsing message is not acceptable.

Comment: So there is no option in Json.NET accpetable for you, or you have to modify Json.NET source. I added decompiled code in anwser which is responsible for this error.

Comment: Unfortunately. I hope this will be handled better in future JSON.NET version (e.g. more specific exception will be throwed instead of general JsonSerializationException).